# Select a image to be uploaded from URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, file-upload

I just need the **selected file to be the URL** so when I press suit would be the **URL content**.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
   <input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. The file input gives a file path to a file on the local machine, not a URL to a remote resource. Also, that file path is obfuscated for security reasons, so you cannot enumerate the client's folder structure. Perhaps you'd get a better response to your question if you could tell us what exactly you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: I'm using Forminator plugin for one of my projects with multi-steps form. I want to save the Data for that user-provided so they could continue later and finish inputting all the fields that are still empty. I managed to do it with everything to be saved in my SQL but when I load the data from SQL the file is the only thing I have a problem loading I can't make it preselected to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-selection is not possible with type file, You can use some plugins like http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ or you can use something like this

```css
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
input, textarea{font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.input-group{
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
}
.input-group > label,.input-group > div{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* needed for Safari */
}
.input-group-icon{
  background:#eee;
  color: #777;
  padding: 0 12px
}
.input-group-area{
  width:100%;
}
.input-group input{
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="input-group-icon" for="file">browse...</label>
  <div class="input-group-area"><input type="text" id="preview" placeholder="No file selected..." readonly value="my_drafted_image.png"></div>
       <input type="file" id="file" onchange="document.getElementById('preview').value = this.files.item(0).name" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it for me